# Diarium app & synchronizing between Android & Win10 with OneDrive

Tags: windows, android, onedrive

I am trying to get the Diarium app on my Android device to display the same data on my Windows 10 PC, and vice verca.

Descriptions of the app seem to imply that this is possible (is it?).

When I "sync" 1 device using OneDrive, it creates a directory at "/Apps/Diarium/" and includes the index, database, & media files for that device on it. When I open the OneDrive sync'd Diarium on the other device, nothing shows up and if I "sync" it, it will create another directory on OneDrive at "/Apps/Diarium 1/" with its own separate index, database, & media files.

The app itself does not have much configuration to it. I have both tied to the same gmail account, which happens to also be the Microsoft account that I am using for OneDrive. I have not tried Google Drive yet.

Does anyone know how to accomplish what I am after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using two different app versions - one app version might be too far behind to be sync-compatible with the latest app version, therefore they work on different directories. On Windows, it might be necessary to update to the latest Windows update first in order to update Diarium.

Comment: It ended up being that I had the latest version available for the build of Windows 10 I was using, but not the actual latest version available in general. I was on 1607 and 1803/1809 were the latest at the time.